# PageSpeed Insights Field Data/Origin Summary "does not have sufficient real-world speed data for this page"

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Whenever I use PageSpeed Insights to test my site, I get the following message for both "Field Data" and "Origin Summary": **"The Chrome User Experience Report does not have sufficient real-world speed data for this page."**

Our site has been up for years using WordPress. Why won't Google generate these fields?

Comment: I've read on multiple sources that it is out of your hands, Google decides whether they have enough data for 'real-world speed' based on the nr of visitors as far as I have seen. But I can't find any Google Developer comment on it. http://www.thesempost.com/google-shows-real-world-speed-data-pagespeed-insights-tool/

Comment: Is your WordPress version up-to-date? Also; Have you tried switching your theme and test it?

Comment: Yes, WP is up to date. I am using Jevelin, which is a pretty popular premium theme. I don't have the luxury of changing it for testing as it is a corporate site.

Answer (score 0):

Google is now showing these two fields. I still have no idea why that data wasn't there before and why it is there now. Oh well.